# webapi core flunt validation unit test with xunit issue

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

I am working with asp.net core webapi( 6.0). I am using fluent validation for validating.

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string? code { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TransactionDateFrom { get; set; }
}

public class ParameterValidator : AbstractValidator<Parameter>
{
    public ParameterValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(model => model.code)
            .Matches("^ABC.{10}$")
            .WithMessage("**barcode should be 13 char long and starts with ABC**");
        RuleFor(model => model.TransactionDateFrom.ToString())
            .Matches(@"^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$")
            .WithMessage("Date should be in the pattern of **YYYY-MM-DD**");
       
    }
}
```

I am writing unit test using xunit, flunt validation. It does not work

```
[Fact]
    public void Validate_TransactionDateFrom_InValid()
    {
        var param = new Parameter{ TransactionDateFrom = DateTime.Now };
        var result = _validator.TestValidate(param);
        result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(parameter => parameter.TransactionDateFrom);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Validate_code_Format_InValid()
    {
        var param = new Parameter{ code = "2791231231233" };
        var result = _validator.TestValidate(param);
        result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(parameter => parameter.code);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @itmannz, what is your `_validator`?

Comment: ParameterValidator  _validator = ParameterValidator();

Comment: Did you use any inheritance model or not? I saw you use `RuleFor(model => model.Flybuys)` but there is no such property in `Parameter`. Or just misspelling?

Comment: Opps, Sorry it's code. I have updated

Comment: Another thing, what do you mean for `It does not work`, do you have any error? `ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor` is used to Assert that there should be a failure for the xxx property. If the assertion fails, then a `ValidationTestException` will be thrown.  For example, if you use `code = "2791231231233"` which has validation error, the assertion should be a suceess.